# Can I use SoX to generate audio?

Tags: sox

For a project I am working on, I need to use the SoX tool for audio generation. If there is a way to use SoX to generate certain notes/tones for a certain duration, please let me know! I have done quite some research on this to no avail.

Moreover, any way to make it output directly into your speakers? I'm thinking something like redirection to /dev/audio.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can synthesise sound effects using `synth` and the `-n` option.
For instance, the following command creates a 3 seconds sine wav at 500 Hz:

```
sox -n -r 8000 output.wav synth 3 sine 500
```

You can set the sample frequancy using the option `-r`. Default value is 48kHz.

You can play audio directly to /dev/audio. If you just need to play the file, and not save it, you can use `play` utility (provided by sox) as follows:

```
play -n -c1 synth 3 sine 500
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot, and I forgot to specify this: Any way to make it output directly into your speakers? I'm thinking something like redirection to /dev/audio, but not sure how I would use SoX like this.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. This is precisely what I needed!