# Why is my memory growing when using Librosa?

Tags: python, librosa, audio-processing

I'm using Librosa and I have a memory problem.

I have a lot of audio files, let's say a hundred.
I process audio files one by one.
Each audio file is loaded by chunks of 1 minute.
Each chunk is processed before I move to the next chunk.
This way, I know that I never have more than 60s of audio in memory at a given time.
This allows me to avoid using too much memory during the whole process.

For some reason, the memory used by the process is growing over time.

Here is a simpler version of the code:

```py
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import psutil

SAMPLING_RATE = 22050
N_FFT = 2048
HOP_LENGTH = 1024

def foo():
    y, sr = librosa.load("clip_04.wav", sr=SAMPLING_RATE, offset=600, duration=60)
    D = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=N_FFT, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH)
    spec_mag = abs(D)
    spec_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec_mag)
    return 42 # I return a constant to make sure the memory is (or should be) released

def main():

    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

    array = []

    for i in range(100):
        foo()
        m = int(process.memory_info().rss / 1024**2)
        array.append(m)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(array)
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.ylabel('MB')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using this code, the memory increases like this:

[image: Memory variation]

Is that normal? And if it is, is there a way to clear Librosa memory at each iteration?

Comment: As a workaround it's always possible to spawn new subprocess (`multiprocessing` module) and stop them when they're done.

Comment: Although is there any way to reproduce the issue without having the `clip_04.wav` file?

Comment: Thanks for the multiprocessing suggestion. I can share the `clip_04.wav` file if needed of course, but I think this can be verified with any given audio file.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the code self-contained by including an autogenerated audio file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236678/can-i-use-sox-to-generate-audio

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try!

Comment: If you are using librosa v0.8, you could also use the built-in examples: https://librosa.org/doc/main/recordings.html

Comment: Is the [cache](https://librosa.org/doc/main/cache.html) perhaps turned on? If so, you might want to purge it using `librosa.cache.clear()`

Comment: I set the cache level to 10 and I tried to use `librosa.cache.clear()` whitin the for loop -> no change

Comment: I have tried your code with an older *librosa* version (0.6.2) and `librosa.util.example_audio_file()` as audio file. When run for 500 iterations, memory consumption stabilizes after about 100 iterations around roughly 240 MB. What happens in your case, when you run more than 100 iterations?

Comment: I get 477.027 MB. But do you see an increase in memory usage @Hendrik?

Comment: Not after about 100 iterations. It then stays flat, goes up and down a bit.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Unless there is memory pressure, it may not get freed

Comment: I have about 4GB of memory. But at some point, the memory is full and the process crashes.

Comment: I have noticed this behaviour also. [This](https://groups.google.com/g/librosa/c/dpkuXbHEqCQ) might be the beginning of an explanation, but that's not a solution. One option is to use PySoundFile for loading, but there is still the resampling problem. For now, I reduce the amount of files to be handled in a single python process, and run the script several times. Not very elegant, though.

Comment: After reporting this issue to Librosa, I was asked to try to use Soundfile directly to read the wav file. The behaviour still remains. I'm not sure where the problem is really, maybe from macOS? But I really don't know. Here is a link to the ticket: https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1286